# LINQ SequenceEqual returns false but comparing using Except gives different result

Tags: c#, .net, linq, equality

I have two lists that I believe to be *equal* and in same sequence, but when I run `SequenceEqual()` it is returning `false`. See below for pseudo example:

```
// For brevity’s sake assume the two-list data is as follows
List<string> list1 = new List<string> {"1", "2", "3"};
List<string> list2 = new List<string> {"1", "2", "3"};

list1.SequenceEqual(list2); // returning false
list1.Except(list2).Count(); // returning 0
list2.Except(list1).Count(); // returning 0
```

In reality my list data is much larger (~ `8000` items), but I am confused why I would get **0** for both `Except().Count()` yet **false** for `SequenceEqual()`?

Comment: Please provide an actual [mcve]. In your sample code, `list1.SequenceEqual(list2)` would return true, and both `Except` calls would return an empty sequence - *not* an integer.

Comment: Here's a complete example showing that `SequenceEqual` returns true for the lists you've provided: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/766bda056c4d676177ac5f5ae396f8b6

Comment: (There are plenty of reasons why Except can return an empty sequence and SequenceEqual return false though - the obvious ones being due to ordering or duplicate elements. Without an actual [mcve] it's hard to say more than that.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet Understandable and will try to put together a better list data example and analyze that more. Do you happen to know if there is a way to get a collection from SequenceEqual difdences?

Comment: what is contained in your list? Are they primitive type or your custom objects? You could supply an equality comparer class if the elements are your business objects and you want to compare two objects using custom logic.

Comment: Both lists contain strings (guid string values ex format: guid-1234-5678-0987).

Comment: Please, note that `Except` *removes duplicates* and doesn't take *order* into account, that's why `new List<string>() {"1", "2", "3", "1"}.Except(new List<string>() {"3", "2", "1", "3"}).Count()` will return `0` when `SequenceEquals` returns `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do *different* comparisons. As for `Except` it

- Removes *duplicates*
- Doesn't take *order* of items into account
- Ignores items which are in the second argument if they are not present in the first

that's why

```
// Duplicated "2" will be ignored
List<string> list1 = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "2" };
// Duplicated "3" will be ignored
// Order doesn't matter
// "7777777" will be ignored
List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "3", "3", "1", "2", "7777777"};

// 0; since all items within list1 - "1", "2", "3"
// are in the list2, duplicates ignored
int count = list1.Except(list2).Count();
```

When `SequenceEqual` returns `true` if and only if sequences are equal order and duplicates matter. In the example above `SequenceEqual` returns `false` since `list1.Count != list2.Count`, `list1[0] != list2[0]` etc.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko Thanks for the great detailed breakdown. In my case (again I will dig more into the collections) I know that the count is the same between the two and I believe the sequence to match (I will debug this more). However, the string values do contain duplicates in both lists. Based on your description would SequenceEqual return false if both lists count are equal, in same sequence, but contain duplicates?

Comment: @OtoNoOto: `SequenceEqual` is the strictest comparison, it returns `true` if and only if both lists are of the same length and `i`-th item of `list1` and `list2` are equal for *all* `i`. As you can see both duplicates and order matter.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko Thank you. Accepting this as answer as you've provided a very detailed explanation between SequenceEqual and Except.  I will have to debug my data further.